# Using sync thunk with redux toolkit

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I am used to redux toolkit `createAsyncThunk` but recently I wanted to make a thunk to group two `dispatch` calls, like so:

```
const askQuestion = (q: string) => (dispatch: any, getState: any) => {
    dispatch(setQuestion(q))
    dispatch(fetchAnswer(q))
}
```

I just want to call one dispatch after another in something like a function to **avoid repeating code**. I think the best way to do that is to **use a thunk**.

**The problem is** that I don't know how to use a thunk that is **not** async with redux-toolkit. Also, I use **typescript** and I would like my code **strongly typed** (I already have types for AppDispatch for instance).

What is the best way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example thunk that you wrote is correct, as far as the JS code goes.

To get it correctly typed at the TS level, follow the examples we have in the [Redux core docs "TS Usage: Thunks" section](https://redux.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#type-checking-redux-thunks):

```
// app/store.ts
export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
  ReturnType,
  RootState,
  unknown,
  AnyAction
>

// any other file

const askQuestion = (q: string): AppThunk => (dispatch, getState) => {
    // now `dispatch` and `getState` have the right types
    dispatch(setQuestion(q))
    dispatch(fetchAnswer(q))
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Classic thunks rarely explicitly `return` anything and just call `dispatch` a few times, but if you need to wait for the work to be done, you can let the inner function of a thunk return a promise, and then `await` this promise in your `askQuestion` combined thunk: https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks#returning-values-from-thunks

Properly typing everything in a classic thunk has been answered in several other SO questions.

Comment: I don't need to wait for the work to be done, I just want to group dispatch calls so I don't have to repeat the same lines of code elsewhere. Redux Toolkit actually provides a very good solution for async thunks but I don't want async, it makes my code too complex for nothing.